# Excel - find a value in two dimensions

Tags: excel

I have a table of data like this:

```
     a    b    c    d
1    1    2    3    4
2    5    6    7    8
3    9    10   11   12
4    13   14   15   16
```

And I want a formula that finds the maximum value (16) and return its row number (4 in this case). How do I do that?

`INDEX(a1:d1,MATCH(MAX(a1:h4),a1:h4,0),)` ain't working :(

Comment: Sorry, I misclicked in the first place. Edited now

Comment: Function means VBA or macro. Or you need a formula?

Comment: I meant formula! Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sheet layout:
`B1:E1`: column headers
`A2: A5`: row headers
`B2:E5`: data

Array formula:

```
{MAX(IF(B2:E5=MAX(B2:E5);ROW(B2:E5)-1;""}
```

As the question asked for "d" as a result initially, the corresponding array formula is below:

```
{=OFFSET(A1;MAX(IF(B2:E5=MAX(B2:E5);ROW(B2:E5)-1;""));0)}
```

Shift-Ctrl-Enter to in a formula window to insert. Curled brackets are inserted by Excel,not by a user.

Answer (score 2):

And one more humble girl's opinion:

`=ADDRESS(ROW(OFFSET(A1,MAX(IF(B2:E5=MAX(B2:E5),ROW(B2:E5)-1,"")),0)),COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,0,MAX(IF(B2:E5=MAX(B2:E5),COLUMN(B2:E5)-1,"")))),4)` - but entered as **ARRAY** formula via `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`, will return `E5` (assuming `@Jüri Ruut` regions), which is simply the address of the desired cell.

Comment: You might have problems with this if MAX value repeats - if the MAX occurs in E3 and D5 for example then formula returns the address of a cell where MAX doesn't occur! (E5)

Comment: @barryhoudini Agree, but assuming the input there should be only one MAX value, otherwise OP would ask for that)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this attached screenshot is self explanatory?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I would program a macro like that:
Iterate over each row - find the maximum for that row.
Store the value in a array and than compute the maximum again.

Probably it would work with formulas too. Simply compute the maximum of each row in a seperate column and THEN compute the maximum of that column.

Comment: I thought that aswell, but isn't there a single formula that works instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this array formula

`=MIN(IF(A1:H4=MAX(A1:H4),ROW(A1:H4)))`

confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

if there are multiple occurrences of the MAX value in A1:H4 then the formula will give you the **first**  row in which it occurs